# Select a file in Xilinx package IP and process it

Tags: file, tcl, xilinx, vivado

I need to set a sample of the input data to my customized IP in order to adjust the Q point over the multiplications. Is there a way to customize the IP for selecting a file and processing it?

For example, suppose that the `I_file.dat` and the `Q_file.dat` have the following values:

```
I_file.dat    Q_file.dat
------------------------
  0.25          0.60
  0.30          0.65
  0.35          0.70
  0.40          0.65
  0.45          0.60
  0.50          0.55
  0.55          0.50
  0.60          0.45
  0.55          0.40
  0.50          0.35
  ...           ...
```

I need to specify both files to the IP and, later, calculate the absolute value as

[image]

because I and Q are the components of a complex number.

And finally, select the maximum over all values...

How can I do it? Is it possible? Is it possible to use Python or Tcl scripts that use Python scripts to process data when an IP is created? I have read the Xilinx IP customization guide, but I don't find anything about how to select files or uses Python scripts or similar.

Comment: What is "IP" in this context? [Intellectual property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property)?

Comment: Yes. Xilinx offers a GUI to customize your own IP's.

Comment: Why would you keep two components of a series of complex numbers in separate files? That's just asking for trouble…